# How can I map the F4 key's default functionality to trigger a key sequence rather than open Launchpad? (Mountain Lion)

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook-pro

I will use the touchpad gesture to open Launchpad. I don't use Launchpad much.

I'd like to map the F4-key (which opens Launchpad) to send the Keystroke <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> so I can use the OSX screenshot feature with it.

BetterTouchTool does not allow me to do it because it does not recognize when I press this key. I can get BTT to recognize F4 (i.e. hold <kbd>fn</kbd> then press F4) but this is not ideal: I need the top row to mostly function the way they already do while also not requiring pressing <kbd>fn</kbd> to take a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less exactly what I wanted.

http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/

Works perfectly and no BTT is needed for setting the keyboard shortcut (Do it through Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts in System Prefs)

Answer (score 0):

Using [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/), you could also add this to
[private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

`<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::LAUNCHPAD, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::KEY_4, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>`

See the source for the [key code constants](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/tree/version_8.0.0/src/core/server/Resources/include/checkbox/).